# Is it necessary to add a respawn line to make the service run in startup?

Tags: server, scripts, startup

I'm trying to run a service when the system starts up by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples)

I have a script named `service`.

To make it run on startup, I ran

```
 sudo update-rc.d service enable
```

and then rebooted using `sudo reboot` and it works.

I'm curious as to whether I need to **add a respawn line** or not since it is used in this article. In my case it works even I do not add that line.

> Add a respawn line for this service at the bottom of the `/etc/inittab`
>   file. Here's a generic example:
>
> ```
> /etc/inittab
>
> id:2345:respawn:/bin/sh /path/to/application/startup
> ```

My Ubuntu version : 14.04

Comment: If that article uses `/etc/inittab`, it is *really* outdated. No current version of Ubuntu uses it. What version are you using?

Comment: @muru 14.04. So I can just ignore that part ?

Comment: If you're using 14.04, use an Upstart job instead of `/etc/init.d/` scripts.

Comment: @muru What's the difference ? It working also

Comment: Because Upstart jobs can respawn, but without `inittab` (which isn't used anyway), `init.d` scripts can't.

Comment: @muru You mean I should not follow this  http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example ?

Comment: @muru what is the used of respawn ? I use `init.d` without respawn it still working fine. Can you explain more ? I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Respawn automatically restarts the service if it crashes.

Comment: @muru So I just put your code in the terminal ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/910/158442

Comment: @muru the answer already include respawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respawn command is used to restart a process if it is not running currently in the system. If the process get stopped in the system, then `respawn` can be used to trigger the starting of the process.